# Follow hyperlink only if submenu is active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying all night to make the .sidebar-menu li a to act as a target hyperlink but unfortunately it's still activating the submenu. I tried with the below javascript to make it a target link without success. Am i missing something here? P.S.: the code is for a mobile platform.

```js
<script>
        $('.sidebar-menu li a').click(function(e){
    if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('submenu-active')) {
        $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('submenu-active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('submenu-active');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        return true;
    }
});</script>
```

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="best-practice.htm" class="show-submenu">Best Practice<i class="fa fa-last fa-caret-right"></i>
    </a>
 <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="best-practice.htm#tab1">Cement &amp; Process<i class="fa fa-last fa-circle"></i></a>
      </li> 
    </ul>                
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You mean when you have submenu-active class already added (submenu visible), then you just want to open the hyperlink specified in the anchor tag ?

Comment: Same question as Sambhav because from my understanding a target link, targets another spot on the same page, unless that is what you're trying to do?

Comment: The hyperlink should have 2 levels: first it opens the submenu, then it can act as a href target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correnctly (complete sample http://codepen.io/kvic2/pen/rOVJVL)

Render your HTML first without `href` attribute for `show-submenu` class but instead with `data-href` attribute:

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li>
    <a data-href="best-practice.htm" class="show-submenu">Best Practice<i class="fa fa-last fa-caret-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li><a href="best-practice.htm#tab1">Cement &amp; Process<i class="fa fa-last fa-circle"></i></a>
      </li> 
    </ul>                
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
.show-submenu{ cursor: pointer; }

.submenu{ display: none; }
```

**scripts**

On click add attribute `href` and set it's value to `data-href` attribute value. Show submenu:

```
$(function(){
  $('.show-submenu').click(function(e){    
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).unbind('click');
    $('.submenu').show();
    $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('data-href')).attr('target', '_blank');    
  });
});
```

**UPDATE**

Modified [example](http://codepen.io/kvic2/pen/rOVJVL) to add `close`-button to submenu item

```
<ul class="sidebar-menu">
  <li>
    <a href="best-practice.htm" target="_blank" class="show-submenu">Best Practice<i class="fa fa-last fa-caret-right"></i>
    </a>
    <ul class="submenu">
    <li><span class="close">(close)</span><a href="best-practice.htm#tab1">Cement &amp; Process<i class="fa fa-last fa-circle"></i></a>
      </li> 
    </ul>                
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.show-submenu{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.submenu{
  display: none;
}

.close{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

**scripts**

```
$(function(){
  $('.show-submenu').click(function(e){    
    if ($(this).next('.submenu:visible').length){
      console.log('sub menu is visible - open new tab');      
      return true;      
    }    
    console.log('sub menu is hidden - show it');
    e.preventDefault();    
    $('.submenu').show();    
  });

  $('.close').click(function(){
    $(this).parents('.submenu').hide();
  });
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. But  i remembered now that also what if i want to close back the submenu?

Comment: But you want a menu item to be a link and to close the submenu? This is strange:) I think, you must choose - link or open/close submenu.

Comment: i think the best thing for that is to have two "a" linnk. one for opening the submenu and one for the target

Comment: Yes. You can add it to your HTML. I hope, now you know how to do it.

Comment: how can i add a "back" button directly as a first item in the submenu. The "back" button should close the submenu and with your solution it can workout and be standardized.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try :

```js
 $('.sidebar-menu li a').click(function(e){
     if(!$(this).parent().hasClass('submenu-active')) {
        
        $('.sidebar-menu li').removeClass('submenu-active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('submenu-active');
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');
    }
})
```

Basically, just manually extracting the href and redirecting the window to the href.